# Can someone confirm that there are 305,487 words in the Tanach?

Tags: jewish-books, tanach, statistics

about 10 years ago, I wrote a comprehensive Gematria Calculator which calculated every possible sequential gematria in the whole Torah and Tehillim.

### http://www.secretorah.com

Now I expanded it for the rest of the Tanach.

My system calculated 305,487 words in the whole Tanach. Can someone confirm this???

Comment: Torah Tidbits has "parsha statistics" each week for the Parsha at http://ttidbits.com/ You would need to check back issues each week for the statistics and add them up.

Comment: Which version of Tanakh are you using?

Comment: @DoubleAA - LOL gave me a good laugh.

Comment: @EzraHoerster What was funny?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Because ideally all Tanachs should have the same amount of words...unless they are messed with.

Comment: @EzraHoerster Perhaps ideally, but that's simply not the case today, nor in the recent past. I don't know what's funny about this. Even back in the Talmud they had arguments about if certain word/phrases were written together as one word or not.

Comment: Here is a simple lesson: 
**Tanach** is an abbriviation of : **Torah, Nevi'im, Ketuvim**.

My calculation showed that its 305487 words. I want someone to confirm that!!!

 Please understand that Tanach and Torah are not the same!!!